# Image of a ball under continous map

Tags: real-analysis

This seems like a classic result, but I have not ever met:

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ is a continuous map such that $|f(x)-f(y)|\geq |x-y|$ for all $x,y\in \mathbb{R}^m$. If $f(0)=0$, prove that $B_r(0)\subset f(B_r(0)),$ where $B_r(0)=${$x\in \Bbb R^m,|x|<r$}.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I post a minimal solution , but in this situation there are many easy ways to show this result.I suggest you to prove differently . Have a good day

Comment: I have tried quite many ways. I think it is more complicated than it looks. Maybe it needs some results from functional analysis or algebra.

Comment: you are right I take I thought you asked something different

Comment: @Nishikata you should add what you have tried in your question itself to show that it's adequately motivated. This prevents the question from closing or getting deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We note that $f:\Bbb R^m\to \Bbb R^m$ is injective since$f(x)=f(y)\implies 0\ge|x-y|\implies x=y$ . Now we use the [Invariance of domain theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain) which states that if U is an open subset of $\Bbb R^m $ and $f:U\to\Bbb R^m$ is an injective continuous map then, $V:= f(U) $ is open in $\Bbb R^m$ and $f:U\to V$ is an homeomorphism. Let be $U:= B_r(0) $ and let the $ i :V\to U$ which for the exists for the Invariance of domain theorems and is an Homeo. We have that $ i :V\to U$ is 1-Lipschitz and $ i(0)=0$ . Now the problem is equivalent to $i(B_r(0)) \subset B_r(0)$.

Now this is obvious since if $|x| < r$ then $|i(x)| \leq |x| < r$ and thus the fact that $i(x) \in B_r(0)$ using the [Filippo Giovagnini](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/676714/filippo-giovagnini) answer.

Comment: Good point! I think we cannot avoid the Invariance of domain theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Simply consider that $f : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ has to be injective ($f(x)=f(y)$ implies $0 \geq |x-y|$). Let us define $i : f(\mathbb{R}^d) \to \mathbb{R}^d$ be the inverse of $f$. We have by assumption that $i$ is $1$-Lipschitz and $i(0)=0$. Thus the problem is equivalent to $i(B_r(0)) \subset B_r(0)$.

Now this is obvious since if $|x| < r$ then $|i(x)| \leq |x| < r$ and thus the fact that $i(x) \in B_r(0)$.

Comment: Since we don't necessarily have $f$ is bijective, how do you show $B_r(0) \subseteq f(B_r(0)) \iff i(B_r(0)) \subseteq B_r(0)$